# Spying on an instance method with Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class with several methods, e.g.

```
class MyClass
  def method_a(p)
    method_b if p == 1
  end

  def method_b
    some_more_stuff
  end
end
```

And I wish to test, using RSpec, that `method_a` (sometimes) calls `method_b`.

```
it 'calls method_b if the passed parameter is 1' do
  instance = spy('MyClass')

  instance.method_a(1)

  expect(instance).to have_received(:method_b)
end
```

Unfortunately, because RSpec spies don't pass on method calls to the thing they're spying on, `spy.method_a` does not in fact call `spy.method_b`. I've tried playing around with doubles and instance doubles, but am now horribly confused.

How can I have an RSpec double or spy or other instance object observe an instance's internal method calls without completely replacing them? I'm open to mocking out `method_b` in some manner, but can't figure out how to do that properly either.

Comment: Why do you need to use `spy('MyClass')` instead of an actual instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: Just don’t test like this. You shouldn’t be testing what happens in the internals of a class. Only test things you can actually see from the outside.

Answer (score 6):

Generally I don't recommend testing things like this way, since method call is a completely internal thing. Remember, RSpec is *BDD* framework, and BDD is not about internal things.

However, I understand sometimes we want to test internal things using mocks and stubs. So, here's an example code:

```rb
RSpec.describe MyClass do
  it 'calls method_b if the passed parameter is 1' do
    instance = MyClass.new
    expect(instance).to receive(:method_a).and_call_original
    expect(instance).to receive(:method_b)

    instance.method_a(1)
  end
end
```

The key part is that we *actually* instantiate `MyClass` so that we can use [`and_call_original`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation) method only available on [`partial test doubles`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/basics/partial-test-doubles).